# how to capture tomcat console output in a log file

Tags: windows, tomcat, logging, tomcat9

The install process, rather than simply extracting a zip file, has been used to install Tomcat.  Thanks to the install, it is registered on the Windows server as a Windows Service.  An xml file containing a  element has been placed into **conf/Catalina/localhost**.

Before running the server as a service, the goal is to make sure that the application is logging to a text file, not just the console.  So upon using the batch file **bin/startup.bat** from the command line, the tomcat and the app we are trying to start, starts up just fine and lots of info is seen in the console output.

The problem is that everything being displayed in the console from the application is NOT showing up in any log files.

How does tomcat need to be configured to capture the console output for this given application to a physical log file?

Comment: Refer https://serverfault.com/questions/252934/how-to-redirect-tomcat-console-log-to-files-tomcat-started-via-windows-bat to configure console logging in file.

Comment: @Pandurang, I am sorry to say but that link didn't do me any good.  The only thing with a green check mark was the one to remove the **java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler** from the .handlers.  I admin that  I don't expect disabling 1 of the 2 handlers, I was not surprised to see no change.  So I am still looking for thoughts.

Comment: @Riley  if I understand your question correctly you want to setup tomcat as a windows service and have access to the stdout log file. Have you checked the link https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/windows-service-howto.html ?  This contains all the information you need. Since this is windows tail is not an option but you should be able to direct the output to a log file.

Comment: @souser, actually that is not the case.  I just updated my question to try to make it more clear.  In short, the app is logged only to the console, not to a log file.  How to change that?

Comment: Usually, developers achieve application logging by configuring the details in their application log4j xml file. In other words, this is done outside of the tomcat.

Comment: But again, if all you are trying to do is take the output from the console and put it in a log file you can use the options ```--StdOutput``` and ```--StdError``` as mentioned in the link I provided earlier

Comment: @souser, I see the wisdom of what you say.  Here is the scope, the application I am trying to run is not one I wrote, rather I have a war file and have created an xml file that contains the Context element, which unzips the war file.  There is also a local.properties files which is also referenced within a Resource element.  Does something need to happen in this file to wire up logging correctly?

Comment: @souser with respect to --StdError/--StdOutput, my desire is to get logging to work correctly in general so that it works the same way when run from the cmdline or as a service.  From what I am seeing, the link is only about running it as a service.